# How can I prevent a property from updating, which is marked as "UseNpgsqlIdentityAlwaysColumn()" using npgsql - postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, ef-core-2.2

I use postgresql db with entityframework core and npgsql core. I have a property named "Index" which is Identity type column. Index column is not the ID column, but it is a db generated sequence column. It is marked with "UseNpgsqlIdentityAlwaysColumn()" to generate value by db on add.

There is no problem with the insert(add) operation. But, while updating the entity I get the error "428C9: column "index" can only be updated to DEFAULT"

I tried to mark as "ValueGeneratedOnAdd()". But it didn't help.

```
builder.Property(x => x.Index).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().UseNpgsqlIdentityAlwaysColumn();
```

How can I update the entity ignoring the "Index" property?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you trying to update the value of the index property? If so, that's not possible with an IDENTITY *ALWAYS* column, but is possible with an IDENTITY *BY DEFAULT* column. If you have a different problem, can you please post a full code sample?

Comment: Regardless there's no need to specify `ValueGeneratedOnAdd`

Answer (score 1):

Some nasty workaround to mark it as unmodified. Just use some repository pattern and vuola

```
 db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
 db.Entry(model).Property(x => x.Index).IsModified = false;
 db.SaveChanges();
```